# curl sftp uploads empty file without error

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, curl

How can I solve or better troubleshoot the following problem?
I need to upload a text file using curl via sftp to a remote server.

Authentication works, no error returned, but the file is created empty on the server

Expect a non-empty file to be uploaded:

```
curl -v -T file.txt -u username:password sftp://hostname.com

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying **.*.**.***...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hostname.com (**.*.**.***) port 22 (#0)
* User: username
* completed keyboard interactive authentication
* Authentication complete
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host hostname.com left intact
```

However, uploading the same file using "sftp" tool works fine, created file is NOT empty:

```
sftp sftp://username@hostname.com:22
Connected to hostname.com.
sftp\> put file.txt
Uploading file.txt to /file.txt
sftp\>
```

curl version 7.61.1
Using Oracle Linux Server 8.5

Many thanks!